# how to send php array data to javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, json

Here is the php array i am using. I am trying to convert each entry into a string and pass it to the javascript variable, but when i use the following code I only get the first letter of each word in the php array.

```
<?php 
$terms = array('cat', 'dog', 'bird');
$rand_keys = array_rand($terms);
?>
```

Javascript variable with php array data

```
var searchterms = <?php echo json_encode($terms[$rand_keys]); ?>;
```

Comment: you want to create a js variable for each element of php array or any one js variable for random php array element.

Answer (score 2):

use `shuffle($terms);` then `echo json_encode( $terms );`

Comment: this works great but when what if i wanted to dd many more terms to the php array. i looked at the source and it displays all the terms like this var searchterms = ["slamjam","kenny","opp","heel","dog","bird","lol","flip","aaa","juu","sam","stern","ben","upndon","cat"];  is there any way to make it display one term at a time?

Comment: @Dan are you converting searchterms to a json object?

Comment: @Dan yup :) since it is a trusted source you can use eval(), then you can navigate the json object similar to an array (searchterms[0] will show the first value)

Answer (score 1):

The following code just take a random element from the php array and not the whole array:

`var searchterms = <?php echo json_encode($terms[$rand_keys]); ?>;`

Use the following code to get all the elemenets:

`var searchterms = <?php foreach ($terms as $t){echo json_encode($t);} ?>`